# laravel htaccess not work

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to rewrite this url : `sample.com/panel/index.php/api/users?page=1` to `sample.com/panel/api/users?page=1` (remove `index.php`)
and here is my `.htaccess` file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

but that is not work ! why ?

i use from apache2 ver 2.4 in ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked whether mod_write is enabled?: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Have you check whether the virtual host is allowed to use .htaccess? Requires `AllowOverride all` in your virtual host configuration.

Comment: Laravel is placed in a subdirecty? You can set a `RewriteBase /panel/` to let mod_rewrite know to start rewriting form there.